# my app is continuously crashing due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is crashing due to memory pressure but I have already removed all UIViews when I don't need them. But app is still crashing a lot. I am new in memory management and I would greatly appreciate some help.
P.S- My app size is 220mb

Answer (score 1):

You must identify what is consuming the memory. It's probably a "strong reference cycle" (aka a "retain cycle"), but it's impossible to say on the basis of the limited information provided.

See the Instruments demonstration in the WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242) for demonstration of how to use Instruments to identify memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may be loading assets or files in general that are big in size and take up a lot of memory. Give us more info about the app.

Comment: Yes you are right Ivan my app has so many images that is why its size is almost 220 mb but i can't remove them. Can you please tell me how can I unload/remove them in viewDidDisappear or any other inbuilt method?

Comment: do you cache the images in some collection? maybe if you show us some code that takes care of image loading we can give you a hint :)

Comment: Take all your images out. Change them to png if not already, goto https://tinypng.com and upload your images so there, download the new images. Replace the new images with the olds and tada your game should be around 50-70% smaller

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the views will not free all the memory. 
You need to clean the cache as well.
Try calling this and check your result with Instruments:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Maybe you also have some memory leaks and/or caching big files like images or videos. 
If you are using e.g. the SDImageCache you can free it like follows:

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
[imageCache clearMemory];
[imageCache clearDisk];
```

It's hard to say what it could be. To get more information you should use the "leaks" tool in Instrument to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out what takes so much memory. A good way to inspect your app is using Instruments. It's part of every Xcode installation.

Here's a pretty good intro into it: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

You are looking for the Allocations and the Leaks view.

Good luck.